# Proper architecture for Node.js modules and database connectivity?

Tags: architecture, node.js

I'm writing a Node app that accepts TCP connections. I have a few separate Node modules (utilizing the exports functionality). Each needs a database connection to handle some of their functionality.

What's the best way to architect/handle database connections? Should each module create a separate connection or should my main JS file pass in a database connection handler to the modules when I require them?

Comment: The question is too hard to answer without more specific details, however feel free to visit the [node.js chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/642/node-js) for more detailed discussion

Comment: I agree my question is very general, but this type of architecture is probably common in Node.js apps. Most will require() many installed and custom modules, I assume someone has tried either way before and has experience in the flexibility and robustness of each method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

imo best approach is to initialize connections pool and use it in modules passing as parameter. 
[mysql-pool](https://github.com/Kijewski/node-mysql-pool) is quite generic and easily adaptable to any db client

upd: [node-pool](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool) is a generic db-agnostic pool

Comment: Actually I think using https://github.com/springmeyer/node-pool is better, since it's more general than just using a mysql pool (you can use it with all kind of dbs).

Comment: I agree, I've started rewriting my code this way and it required very few changes. Allows for the modules to ignore database connection configuration, which IMO is a good thing.

Comment: springmeyer/node-pool seems to 404, but I wrote a node.js pool library that is available from NPM and has gotten a fair amount of use: https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool